# Is there any way to only undecorate the main window in an application while keeping nested windows decorated?

Tags: ubuntu, xfce, gtk, ubuntu-unity, xfce4

I'm wanting to remove the title bar/min/max/close buttons from just the main window of an application running on XFCE (though I am able to switch to a different desktop environment if necessary).

I need to be able to remove the window decorations while still having the subwindows within that window decorated, is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can set that with the decorated property. See https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkWindow.html#gtk-window-set-decorated

You need to set it decorated/undecorated for each window per your liking.